# Python: Find a name in a list of lists

Tags: python, string, list

So, I've to search for a name in a list and the code has to give me all the contacts with that name.
Ex:
My code is:

```
def find_contacts(contacts = [['Bruno Jr', '@brunojr'], ['Brunosvaldo Kean', 'brunosvaldo_kean']], name = 'Bruno'):
    for list in contacts:
        if name in list:
            print(name)
```

The output should be [['Bruno Jr'],[Brunosvaldo Kean]] but instead I get nothing, I really don't know why Python won't give me the names. Someone please help me understand the error.

Comment: In the line above `if` add print statements for `name` and `list`. This way you will know for which values `name in list` is false when you expect it to be true.

Comment: You need to specify which string in the sub lists you want `in` to test otherwise it only will find a complete match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find items that contain `name`, try this:

```
def find_contacts(contacts = [['Bruno Jr', '@brunojr'], ['Brunosvaldo Kean', 'brunosvaldo_kean']], name = 'Bruno'):
  for list in contacts:
    for item in list:
      if name in item:
        print(name)

find_contacts()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this list of lists and name:

```
>>> LoL=[['Bruno Jr', '@brunojr'], ['Brunosvaldo Kean', 'brunosvaldo_kean']]
>>> name='Bruno'
```

You need to specify which of the elements of each sub list you are applying `in` to otherwise it is looking for a total match in the list (ie, is `'Bruno'` in the sublist, not `'Bruno Jr.'`):

```
>>> [sl[0] for sl in LoL if name in sl[0]]
['Bruno Jr', 'Brunosvaldo Kean']
```

Alternatively, if you want to test every string in the sub list, you can use `any`:

```
>>> [sl[0] for sl in LoL if any(name in s for s in sl)]
['Bruno Jr', 'Brunosvaldo Kean']
```

With `.upper()` and `any` you can do a case insensitive search against all the strings:

```
>>> [sl[0] for sl in LoL if any('KEAN' in s.upper() for s in sl)]
['Brunosvaldo Kean']
```

Comment: Now I feel very dumb because it was so simple afterall. Thank you!

Comment: Don't feel dumb! It is a totally understandable confusion of context -- what does this `in` apply to here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't name your vars like 'list' - it's python built-in. Nevertheless - code is almost ok but your if condition won't work since you don't have exact name 'Bruno' as list elem. What you do is checking if 'Bruno' is in ['Bruno Jr', '@brunojr'] - to quickly fix it you should probably search in first elem which is name string:

```
def find_contacts(contacts = [['Bruno Jr', '@brunojr'], ['Brunosvaldo Kean', 'brunosvaldo_kean']], name = 'Bruno'):
    for person_list_data in contacts:
        if name in person_list_data[0]:
            print(name)
```

However, be aware of out of range error.